# Convert dataframe to scala map

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe like,

```
df.show
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|  20|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

I need to put it in a scala Map like `(Michael->20,Andy->30,Justin->19)`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plain and simple - convert to static types and collect:

```
df.select($"name", $"age".cast("int")).as[(String, Int)].collect.toMap
```

Though in practice there you won't find much use for that I guess, given it stores data in the driver memory.